# How to store inputed table shiny

Tags: r, shiny, user-input

I have this shiny app. The main aim is to upload excel sheet with data and plot some graphs in tabs. User is able to select a sheet to make the graph. The seet will render to observe the selected data. This works well.

But I am struggling to manipulate with input data to make the graph.

I tried to use reactive value named data and then make the graph from that. I am quite new with shiny apps.

library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("OTD project update"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Insert File', accept = c(".xlsx")),
    textInput('file1sheet','Name of Sheet (Case-Sensitive)')),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    type = "tabs",
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("value")),
    tabPanel("OTD", plotOutput("OTD"))        
    )   
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
  sheets_name <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
      return(excel_sheets(path = input$file1$datapath))  
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  
  output$value <- renderTable({
    if (!is.null(input$file1) && 
        (input$file1sheet %in% sheets_name())) {
      return(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, 
                        sheet = input$file1sheet))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  
  
  data <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$file1) && 
        (input$file1sheet %in% sheets_name())) {
      return(read_excel(input$datapath, 
                        sheet = input$file1sheet))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

    
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to use the sheet names in radio buttons to pick instead of typing it. Also, there was a typo.  Try this

```
library(shiny) 
library(readxl) 
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("OTD project update"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Insert File', accept = c(".xlsx")),
    #textInput('file1sheet','Name of Sheet (Case-Sensitive)')
    uiOutput("sheet")
  ),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    type = "tabs",
    tabPanel("Data", DTOutput("table")),
    tabPanel("OTD", plotOutput("plot"))      
  )   
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  sheets_name <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
      return(excel_sheets(path = input$file1$datapath))  
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  data <- reactive({
    req(sheets_name())
    if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
      return(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, sheet = input$mysheet))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  
  output$sheet <- renderUI({
    req(sheets_name())
    radioButtons("mysheet", "Select a Sheet", choices = sheets_name())
  })
 
  output$table <- renderDT(data())
  output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(cars)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```